# If Jinn can manipulate real life objects as in Solomon story, why don't they conquer us?

Tags: jinn

In Story of Soleiman, a jinn of his brought something to happen at near instant speed in a distant country.

If Jinn can do that why don't we see instances of them messing with the human world, levitating objects and scaring us, or even conquering humanity with their superior power?

We're like sheep for them. Powerless. They see us but we can't see them. And they have superior power and abilities.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about our site and model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinn are not the strongest creature in the earth, angels are more strong, and there are some humans also which are more strong than jinns...

## Jinns vs Angels

See the weakness of the jinn versus the angels, for example in:

<sub>Surah 8. Al-Anfal (The Spoils of War), Ayaat 47 To 49:</sub>

> And be not like those who come out of their homes boastfully and to be seen of men, and hinder (men) from the path of Allah; and Allah is Muhit (eneompassing and thoroughly comprehending) all that they do. And (remember) when **Satan made their (evil) deeds seem fair to them** and said, "No one of mankind can overcome you this day (of the battle of Badr) and verily, I am your neighbor (for each and every help)." **But when the two forces came in sight of each other, he ran away and** said "Verily, I have nothing to do with you. Verily, **I see what you see not**. Verily, I fear Allah for Allah is severe in punishment." When the hypocrites and those in whose hearts was a disease (of disbelief) said: "These people (Muslims) are deceived by their religion." But whoever puts his trust in Allah, then surely, Allah is All-Mighty, All-Wise.

<sub>from Tafsir Ibn Kathir - Surah 8. Al-Anfal, Ayaat 47 To 49:</sub>

> After Allah commanded the believers to fight in His cause sincerely and to be mindful of Him, He commanded not to imitate the idolators, who went out of their homes (boastfully) to suppress the truth, (and to be seen of men), boasting arrogantly with people. When Abu Jahl was told that the caravan escaped safely, so they should return to Makkah, he commented, "No, by Allah! We will not go back until we proceed to the well of Badr, slaughter camels, drink alcohol and female singers sing to us. This way, the Arabs will always talk about our stance and what we did on that day." However, all of this came back to haunt Abu Jahl, because when they proceeded to the well of Badr, they brought themselves to death; and in the aftermath of Badr, they were thrown in the well of Badr, dead, disgraced, humiliated, despised and miserable in an everlasting, eternal torment. This is why Allah said here, (and Allah is Muhit (encompassing and thoroughly comprehending) all that they do.) He knows how and what they came for, and this is why He made them taste the worst punishment. Ibn Abbas, Mujahid, Qatadah, Ad-Dahhak and As-Suddi commented on Allah's statement, (And be not like those who come out of their homes boastfully and to be seen of men,) "They were the idolators who fought against the Messenger of Allah at Badr." Muhammad bin Ka'b said, "When the Quraysh left Makkah towards Badr, they brought female singers and drums along. Allah revealed this verse, (And be not like those who come out of their homes boastfully and to be seen of men, and hinder (men) from the path of Allah; and Allah is Muhit (encompassing and thoroughly comprehending) all that they do.)
>
> -Satan makes Evil seem fair and deceives the Idolators
>
> Allah said next, (And (remember) when Satan made their (evil) deeds seem fair to them and said, "No one of mankind can overcome you today and verily, I am your neighbor.")
>
> Satan, may Allah curse him, made the idolators' purpose for marching seem fair to them. He made them think that no other people could defeat them that day. He also ruled out the possibility that their enemies, the tribe of Bani Bakr, would attack Makkah, saying, "I am your neighbor." **Satan appeared to them in the shape of Suraqah bin Malik bin Jushum**, the chief of Bani Mudlij, so that, as Allah described them, (He Satan makes promises to them, and arouses in them false desires; and Satan's promises are nothing but deceptions) 4:120.
>
> Ibn Jurayj said that Ibn Abbas commented on this Ayah, (8:48) "On the day of Badr, Satan, as well as, his flag holder and soldiers, accompanied the idolators. He whispered to the hearts of the idolators, "None can defeat you today! I am your neighbor." When they met the Muslims and **Satan witnessed the angels coming to their aid, (he ran away)**, he went away in flight while proclaiming, (Verily, I see what you see not.)"
>
> Ali bin Abi Talhah said, that Ibn Abbas said about this Ayah, ("No one of mankind can overcome you today and verily, I am your neighbor") 
>   "Satan, as well as, his devil army and flag holders, came on the day of Badr in the shape of a Suraqah bin Malik bin Jushum, man from Bani Mudlij, Satan said to idolators, "None will defeat you this day, and I will help you." When the two armies stood face to face, the Messenger of Allah took a handful of sand and threw it at the faces of the idolators, causing them to retreat. **Jibril (an angel), peace be upon him, came towards Satan, but when Satan, while holding the hand of a Mushrik man, saw him, he withdrew his hand and ran away with his soldiers. That man asked him, "O Suraqah! You claimed that you are our neighbor" He said, (Verily, I see what you see not. Verily, I fear Allah for Allah is severe in punishment)**
>
> Satan said this when he saw the angels."

## Jinns vs Humans

Now let's see the weakness of the jinn versus the human, for example in the same verse that you used to describe the power of Jinns (the Solomon story):

<sub>Surah 27. An-Naml (The Ants), Ayaat 38 To 40:</sub>

> He (Solomon) said: "O chiefs! Which of you can bring me her throne before they come to me surrendering themselves in obedience (as Muslims)". **An Ifrit from the Jinn said: "I will bring it to you before you rise from your place.** And verily, I am indeed strong and trustworthy for such work". **One with whom was knowledge of the Scripture, said: "I will bring it to you within the twinkling of an eye!"** Then when he saw it placed before him, he (Solomon) said: "This is by the grace of my Lord -- to test me whether I am grateful or ungrateful! And whoever is grateful, truly, his gratitude is for himself; and whoever is ungrateful, certainly my Lord is Rich, Bountiful."

<sub>from Tafsir Ibn Kathir- Surah 27. An-Naml, Ayaat 38 To 40</sub>

> ...
>   (One with whom was knowledge of the Scripture said: ) Ibn Abbas said, "**This was Asif, the scribe of Solomon.**" It was also narrated by Muhammad bin Ishaq from Yazid bin Ruman that he was Asif bin Barkhiya' and he was a truthful believer who knew the Greatest Name of Allah. Qatadah said: "**He was a believer among the humans, and his name was Asif**." (I will bring it to you within the twinkling of an eye!) Meaning, lift your gaze and look as far as you can, and before you get tired and blink, you will find it before you. Then he got up, performed ablution and prayed to Allah, may He be exalted. Mujahid said: "He said, O Owner of majesty and honor." When Solomon and his chiefs saw it before them...

and remember too that in the jinns there are the beleivers and the non beleivers (satans):

<sub>Surah 46. Al-Ahqaf (The Dunes), Ayaat 29 To 31:</sub>

> And We sent to you a small number of Jinn, in order to let them listen to the Quran. So when they arrived there, they said: "Pay attention." Then, when it was finished, they returned to their people, to warn them. They said: "O our people, we have heard a Scripture that was sent down after Moses, authenticating what is present with him. It guides to the truth; and to a Straight Path."   "O our people, respond to God's caller, and believe in Him. He will then forgive your sins, and spare you a painful retribution."

<sub>Surah 72. Al-Jinn ("The Jinn"), Ayaat 1 To 7:</sub>

> Say: "It has been inspired to me that a group of Jinn were listening." They said: "**We have heard a magnificent Quran! It guides to what is correct, so we believed in it**, and we will not set up anyone with our Lord. And exalted is the majesty of our Lord, He has not taken a wife nor a son. **And it was the foolish one amongst us who used to say lies about God.** And we had thought that neither mankind nor the Jinn would ever utter a lie against God. And there were men from among mankind who used to seek help from the men among the Jinn, but they only helped increase them in sin. And they thought as you thought, that God would not send anyone."

<sub>Surah 72. Al-Jinn ("The Jinn"), Ayaat 11 To 12:</sub>

> "**And among us are those who are good doers, and some of us are opposite to that, we are in many paths**. And we acknowledge that we cannot escape God on Earth, nor can we escape Him if we run."

<sub>Surah 72. Al-Jinn ("The Jinn"), Ayaat 14 To 15:</sub>

> "**And among us are those who surrendered, and among us are the compromisers**. As for those who have surrendered, they have sought what is correct. And as for the compromisers, they are firewood for Hell."

Thus in the jinn there are good and infidels. The infidel jinn does not care about oil, gas and gold (this answer your question), but rather about human faith and our entry to Paradise. But this does not mean that the infidel jinn does not wage war on man, but vice versa. The wars of the infidel jinn do not end until the Day of Judgment. See what Satan said to God:

<sub>Surah 38. Sad , Ayaat 71 To 88:</sub>

> For your Lord said to the angels: "I am creating a human being from clay. So when I have evolved him, and breathed into him from My Spirit, then you shall submit to him." The angels submitted, all of them, except Satan; he turned **arrogant**, and became one of the ingrates. He said, "O Satan, what prevented you from submitting to what I have created by My hands? Are you too arrogant? Or are you one of those exalted?" He said, **"I am better than he; You created me from fire, and created him from clay."** He said, "Therefore exit from it, you are outcast. My curse will be upon you until the day of judgment." He said, "My Lord, respite me till the day they are resurrected." He said, "Then, you are granted respite, until the appointed day." He said, "By Your majesty, **I will mislead them all. Except for Your servants who are loyal.**" He (God) said, "The truth, and the truth is what I say. That I will fill hell with you and all those who follow you."

And God told us about the way the infidel jinns fight us , and he described to us that the weapon of jinn is a very weak weapon on the believers but it is a lethal weapon on the infidels, see :

<sub>Surah 14. Ibrahim (Abraham), Ayaat 22:</sub>

> The devil said when the matter was complete: "God had promised you the promise of truth, and I promised you and broke my promise. **I had no power over you except that I invited you and you responded to me. So do not blame me, but blame yourselves**; I cannot help you nor can you help me. I reject that you have set me as a partner before this; the wicked will have a painful retribution."

<sub>Surah 19. Maryam (Mary) , Ayaat 83 to 87:</sub>

> **Did you not see that We send the devils upon the ingrates to drive them into evil?** So do not be impatient; for We are preparing for them a preparation. The day We gather the righteous to the Gracious as a delegation. We drive the criminals to hell as a herd. None will posses intercession, except for he who has taken a pledge with the Gracious.

<sub>Surah 43. Az-Zukhruf (Luxury) , Ayaat 35 to 39:</sub>

> Whosoever turns away from the remembrance of the Gracious, **We appoint a devil to be his constant companion.** They hinder from the path, but they think they are guided! Until he comes to Us, he will say, "Oh, I wish that between you and me were the distance of the two easts. What a miserable companion!" , It would not benefit you this day, for you have transgressed; you are partners in the retribution.

Finally, see how God reassures us that Satan's weapon is weak on the beleivers:

<sub>Surah 4. An-Nisa (The Women) , Ayaat 76:</sub>

> Those who believe do battle for the cause of Allah; and those who disbelieve do battle for the cause of idols. So fight the minions of the devil. Lo! **the devil's strategy is ever weak.**

<sub>Surah 15. Al-Hijr (The Stoneland) , Ayaat 39 to 43:</sub>

> He (Satan) said, "My Lord, you sent me astray, I will make the earth appear beautiful for them, and I will mislead them all, **Except Your devoted servants.**" He (God) said, "This is a straight path to Me. **For My servants, you shall have no authority over them, except those who are misled and follow you.** Hell, shall be the appointed place for them all."

And see who is affected by Satan:

<sub>Surah 26. Ash-Shuara (The_Poets) , Ayaat 221 to 223:</sub>

> Shall I inform you on whom the devils descend? They descend on every **sinful liar**. They claim to listen, but most of them are **liars**.

<sub>I used this site for the Quran translations: https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/1/1/default.htm</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Jinns are not really superior to us. From Quran alone we can understand that humans are the noblest and therefore superior in creation. It was Adam who was "taught all the names" by Allah and created as His caliph (representative, deputy or vicegerent) on Earth ([source](http://tanzil.net/#2:30)) and it was our kind that was made alive by Allah "blowing His spirit" into them. ([Source](http://tanzil.net/#38:72))

Of course, humans are said to be created from clay whereas jinns are created from some sort of a fire. This "superior substance" was apparently the reason for Satan's enmity with Man according to the Quran.

But Quran doesn't specifically refute Satan's argument, but according to the traditional scientific wisdom, Satan does seem to have had his scientific credentials twisted by claiming that clay, a compound substance (soil + water) was inferior to his unitary fire element. For go ask Ibn Sina about it, the famous 11th-century Muslim philosophy and science genius: harmony and balance resulting from a mixed complexion is more conductive to spiritual and intellectual growth than a being limited by properties of a single element. Human soul is believed to emerge from the balance in human humeral makeup in traditional physics after all.

And there's more to learn about jinns, should we consult esoteric sciences. According to what I've read from various esoteric sources which include Muslim esoteric scholars such as [Allama Seyyed Muhammad-Hussain Hussaini Tehrani](http://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%AF_%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%AD%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%86_%D8%AD%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%86%DB%8C_%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C) and non-Muslim esoterists such as [Robert Bruce](https://astraldynamics.com/defense), jinns ("demons" in Western culture) occupy the subtle level of the natural world, corresponding to their fluid body that can appear and disappear in the natural realm. They can also raise to higher levels of existence (malakut) but seldom higher than lower levels of Barzakh or the "astral plane".

They apparently do this by actually physically levitating from the Earth because natural settings are believed to have some correspondence with supernatural states in the esoterist wisdom. This also explains how Jiins trying to overhear revelation can be physically repelled by meteors coming from outer-space. ([source](http://tanzil.net/#37:10)).

Jinns feed on some forms of energy, such as smell of decaying food. They love human form and enjoy music. But they are normally unable to influence us because of our natural protections.

In Islam jinns have free-will and hence come in varieties of personalities. Bad malicious jinns are the ones that may seek to harm us but only if our natural protections are weakened such as by living in dirty places, disregarding hygiene, committing major sins, etc. This answers your question why they normally have no power or influence over us. Indeed, by power of faith and observance which result in strength and elevation in our soul we can reach a point that can subdue jinns. We even have the potential to excel over them even in areas that they have a natural advantage like fast relocation and access to the astral plane. Prophet Muhammad's (pbuh) Isra and Miraj is the prime example of man having the ability to teleportation or rising to the highest metaphysical planes.

Children and women are more vulnerable to their influence because of their "meeker" being and probably because of dominance of humidity in their chemical makeup (jinns made of fire element may be attracted or repelled by the opposite quality, depending on the circumstances).

Jinns particularly detest water, hence water being widely used by exorcists to cure possessed individuals. This also explains why jinns are seldom encountered in modern cities as they are all webbed with water-pipelines and also why they are historically associated with old rural houses.

Evil jinns, demons, are particularly scared by remembrance of Allah, owing to their residence in the subtle level of the natural world where the effects of spiritual invocations are more strongly felt.

So yes, jinns have certain powers but normally it is impossible for them to use them against healthy human individuals. Moreover, they normally can't care less about us because they have their own life and business and have little to do with us "weird" creatures who live so "down to Earth!"